# Getting field values from Window

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a window. and some fields in it (textfield and button). Now i want to submit these details.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: button.up("form").getValues is not a function
```

Button function

```
buClicked : function (button,record) {
var val= button.up('form').getValues();
console.log(val.textfieldValue);
}
```

My Widow Definition

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.WindowForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.winform',
    id: 'winformid',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var val= button.up('form').getForm().getValues();
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked `var val= button.up('window').down('form').getForm().getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `Window's class`  which is okay,but also add items config where ,you will include the `xtype:form` whose config has the `the textfield and the buttons config` something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.WindowForm',
       {
           extend:'Ext.window.Window',
           id:'myformvin',
           items:[
               {xtype:'form',items:[{xtype:'textfield',fieldLabel:'My name',name:'myname'}],
                buttons:[{xtype:'button',text:'save',handler:function(btn){
                        var val =  btn.up('form').getForm().getValues(); 
                        console.log(val); //to confirm that you have the values
                    }
                }]
               }
           ]
       }
);
```